# Php not working after rebooting instance

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I have rebooted my Amazon EC2 instance. Since then, my php is not working. What can I do? I have tried restarting apache but that does not work either..

Comment: we've had this happen before .. Check to see if PHP is still installed ..  Especially if you scaled up?

Comment: I originally had php version 5.3 but updated it to 5.6. Now when I do yum install php, it says "
Error: php56-cli conflicts with php-cli-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php55w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64"

Comment: you need to do a yum remove on both versions of php and then yum install ..

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked after I removed both versions and reinstalled everything:D